# Extra Word spacing of h tag

Tags: html, css

I have `h2` tag and there is content `:before`.

**HTML**

```
<h2 class="glyphicon arrow-heading text-white margin-zero" style="z-index: 1;">
   This is h2 tag and it has word spacing problem
</h2>
```

**CSS**

```
.arrow-heading:before {
  content: "\e072";
  color: #9B0D25;
  float: left;
}

.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.text-white {
  color: #FFF;
}
.margin-zero {
  margin: 0em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}
```

But I get extra spacing as shown below without `text-align: justify;`

[image]

I want **no** extra spacing.

**EDIT**

With `text-align: justify;`

[image]

Comment: Provide text-white, margin-zero classes too

Comment: Do you have `text-align: justify` set somewhere else or applied to the container/parent etc?

Comment: @codyogden `text-align: justify;` is not set anywhere, I inspected the whole html.

Comment: @Junaid: Can you create a demo? I don't see any word spacing issue in the code provided.

Comment: @Junaid Can we get a codepen.io or similar so we can play with it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/n71qsh0j/

Comment: Just align text to left. This will remove any justification.

Comment: Well I am unable to create demo that has issue ... Please check update

Comment: Could it be the `Glyphicon Haflings` font being applied to the entire `<h2>` which throws off "spaces" in the text?

Comment: Or something else, inspect the element on the page, it might be inheriting some unintended css

Comment: @codyogden you are right ... Thanks. Now I move `font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';` from `h2` to `.arrow-heading:before`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answered in the comments, but the `Glyphicon Haflings` font is being applied to the entire `<h2>` tag, and this will cause the spacing problem. The font should only be applied to the element that is specifically containing the Glyphicon.

To increase specificity, you could use an `<i>` tag as the first child of `<h2>`, and another would be (as OP did) moving the `font-family` to the `.arrow-heading:before` selector in your CSS.