# Override font spacing between word - HTML

Tags: html, css

Referring to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568123/extra-word-spacing-of-h-tag), I understand that the font-spacing between words cause the problem.

My question is that is there any CSS way to override the font-spacing (spacing between words) of a font without changing the font ??

Like set spacing between words `2px`

**EDIT**

I want to override the spacing of specific `font-family` ... say `font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';`

Comment: Try `letter-spacing`

Answer (score 2):

I believe, you are talking about word spacing property.

Code like below should work for you...

```
p { 
  word-spacing: 30px;
}
```

Please let me know if any further information is required

Answer (score 1):

CSS has a [`word-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing) property.

```css
p {
  word-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus delectus rerum quam sequi. Dolores aliquam quam ipsa amet expedita totam minima et cupiditate adipisci voluptates corporis autem pariatur, assumenda accusamus, placeat dignissimos aut distinctio hic praesentium tempore incidunt ratione! Doloremque dicta vel quas? Quos ullam labore, quo dignissimos vitae laborum saepe magni rem quia deserunt asperiores eum blanditiis rerum quaerat beatae, velit sint in molestiae voluptate suscipit. Voluptates sint eum, molestiae tempora repellendus est. Iure ut debitis quidem consequuntur praesentium natus molestias culpa impedit voluptates delectus! Animi veritatis, voluptatem aut error nihil eveniet quisquam, facilis in eligendi laudantium doloremque voluptatum.</p>
```